# O Data Service - How to Auto sync data from other system to SFDC external objects?

Tags: rest-api, integration, external-services, externalobjects, odata

From Odata services, I've connected to SAP system. It automatically created an external object and fields based on the table in SAP in SFDC and I created an indirect lookup to the case. I can see the external object data in case related list now.

question 1. When the data is updated in SAP, how to sync it automatically in SFDC to show updated data? or it will be updated only when I click on validate and sync ?

Is there a way we can enable auto-sync data to external objects?

question 2. I need a custom button on case and whenever I click on that I need to show the updated date.

how to achieve this ?